# Multidimensional NSArray

Tags: objective-c

How do I get the `Entry 1`?

---

_contentData Array:

```
(
    {
    id = 1;
    name = "Entry 1";
},
    {
    id = 2;
    name = "Entry 2";
},
)
```

Code:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [_contentData objectAtIndex:0]);

{
id = 1;
name = "Entry 1";
}
```

Code:

```
[_contentData objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0])

Error: Crash App
```

Comment: That's not a multi-dimensional array, that's an array containing two dictionaries (as can be easily determined by the `{}` characters and the presence of the key names).

Comment: Is that error what the console outputs? It should tell you that you’re trying to use objectAtIndex on the wrong type. From there one should log what type it actually is, and then use that class. For example: `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([[_contentData objectAtIndex:0] class]));`

Comment: How do I get the Entry 1? You read the documentation for NSArray and NSDictionary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

what you have here is an `NSdictionnary` inside an `NSArray`
so what you should do is :

`[[_contentData objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"name"]`

Comment: +1 or shorter: `_contentData[0][@"name"]`